# How to append a string to each item in a list to display it in a template?

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I'm trying to set a template that pulls in a comma separated list of hosts, and appends a port to each host.

The list, an ansible fact: `{{ nodes }})` looks like this:

```
node1,node2,node3,...,nodeX
```

And I want the final templated file to look like this:

```
        node1:1234
        node2:1234
        node3:1234
        ...
        nodeX:1234
```

My jinja template currently looks like:

```
"{{ nodes.split(',') | to_nice_json | indent(8) }}"
```

Which gets me:

```
        node1,
        node2,
        node3,
        ...,
        nodeX
```

But, how can I append the port to each node?

I've tried various combinations of

- ```
  {{ nodes.split(',') | join(':1234) | to_nice_json | indent(8) }}
  ```
- ```
  {{ nodes.split(',') | + (':1234) | to_nice_json | indent(8) }}
  ```
- ```
  {% for n in {{ nodes.split(,) }} | zip(':1234') %}
               {{ n[0]n[1] }}
  {% endfor %}
  ```
- etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) in order to repeat the port for each element of the split `nodes` list.
Then, join back the list of lists with a [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.join) in a [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map).
And finally, join everything together, and indent it.

Here would be your template expression:

```
{{ nodes.split(',')
   | product([':1234'])
   | map('join')
   | join('\n')
   | indent(8, True)
}}
```

---

*PS: the second argument to the `indent` filter instruct it to also indent the first line*

> ***first** – Don’t skip indenting the first line*

<sup>*Source: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.indent*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Set a template that pulls in a comma-separated list of hosts, and appends a port to each host."***

The final templated file should look like this:

```
        node1:1234
        node2:1234
        node3:1234
        ...
        nodeX:1234
```

A: The template is very simple

```yaml
shell> cat nodes.txt.j2
{% for n in nodes.split(',') %}
  {{ n }}:1234
{% endfor %}
```

For example, the play

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    nodes: "node1,node2,node3,nodeX"
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: nodes.txt.j2
        dest: /tmp/nodes.txt
```

will create the file

```
shell> cat /tmp/nodes.txt 
  node1:1234
  node2:1234
  node3:1234
  nodeX:1234
```